# Notepad ++ group substitutions using \k

Tags: regex, notepad++, regex-group

How do I use regular expressions in Notepad++ to place all items belonging to a set on one line?

I have a set of practice question answers in the following format:

```
29  Continuous
29  Horizontal mattress
29  Interrupted
29  Vertical mattress
29  No use sutures because the immediate denture acts as a stint
30  1-5 years
30  6-10 years
30  11-15 years
30  16-20 years
30  21-25 years
31  Artery
32  Vitality of the tooth pulp
32  Age of the patient
32  Absence of root resorption
```

I'd like the outcome to be formatted such that each set is on one line:

```
29 Continuous Horizontal mattress Vertical mattress No use sutures because the immediate denture acts as a stint
30 1-5 years 6-10 years 11-15 years 16-20 years 21-25 years
31 Artery
32 Vitality of the tooth pulp Age of the patient Absence of root resorption
```

I wrote the following regex to select the sets:

```
^(?'number'^\d{0,4})\t(.*$)(\n\k<number>(.*))*
```

Substituting with `\1 \2 \4` gives

```
29 Continuous   No use sutures because the immediate denture acts as a stint
30 1-5 years    21-25 years
31 Artery
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: When you use a quantifier applyed to a group, only the last match is kept. That's what you're using with the fourth group that may appear 0 or more times,

Comment: One problem I saw with your regex is that you aren't using a tab in your sample text but two spaces, after fixing this your regex matches, but what you are trying to do is impossible with plain regex. You'll need some programming in a scripting language like Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked out a solution in case anybody is trying to do something similar.

Select the sets with

```
(^(?'number'^\d{0,4})\t(.*$)(\n\k<number>(.*))*)
```

The difference between the originally posted code is the `()` around the entire code

Replace with `\1\n` to create sets in the following format:

```
29  Continuous
29  Horizontal mattress
29  Interrupted
29  Vertical mattress
29  No use sutures because the immediate denture acts as a stint

30  1-5 years
30  6-10 years
30  11-15 years
30  16-20 years
30  21-25 years

31  Artery

32  Vitality of the tooth pulp
32  Age of the patient
32  Absence of root resorption
```

Select the individual lines with

```
(^(?'number'^\d{0,4})\t(.*$))\n
```

Replace with `\3` (two spaces after \3) to create

```
Continuous  Horizontal mattress  Interrupted  Vertical mattress  No use sutures because the immediate denture acts as a stint   
1-5 years  6-10 years  11-15 years  16-20 years  21-25 years    
Artery  
Vitality of the tooth pulp  Age of the patient  Absence of root resorption
```

I don't know how to add the question #s back using regex but it can easily be imported into excel to do that if needed.